# Uncaught reference error: fetchIssues is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a javascript code to store and provide the details filled in the form.It is providing an uncaught reference error. I am unable to find the reason behind it.

```
var form = document.getElementById('issueInputForm');
form.addEventListener('submit',saveIssue);
function fetchIssues()
{
   alert("ssssssaved"); 
}
function saveIssue(e)
{ 
    alert("ssssssaved");
    var id=chance.guid()
    var description = document.getElemenntById("issueDescInput").value;
    var severity = document.getElemenntById("issueSeverityInput").value;
    var assignto = document.getElemenntById("issueAssignedToInput").value;
    var status="Open";
    var summarized={
        id,
        description,
        severity,
        assignto,
        status
    }
    var final=JSON.stringify(summarized);
    if(localStorage.getItem('issues')===NULL)
    {
        var issues[];
        issues.push(summarized);
        var finalissues=JSON.stringify(issues);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', finalissues);
        alert("saved");
    }
    else
    {
        var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
        issues.push(summarized);
        var finalissues=JSON.stringify(issues);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', finalissues);
        alert("saved");
    }
    document.getElementById('issueInputForm').reset();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

HTML code is as below.It invokes fetchIssues onload and saveIssues after submitting. I haven't wrote the code for fetchIssues but it is supposed to take issues from localstorage and display them

```
<body onload="fetchIssues()">
<div class="container">
  <h1>JS Issue Tracker <small>by CodingTheSmartWay.com</small></h1>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
    <form id="issueInputForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issueDescInput">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueDescInput" placeholder="Describe the issue ...">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issueDescInput">Severity</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="issueSeverityInput">
          <option value="Low">Low</option>
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="High">High</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issueDescInput">Assigned To</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueAssignedToInput" placeholder="Enter responsible ...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Probably a typo because `fetchissues` and `fetchIssues` are not the same.

Comment: I can assure that it is not a typo

Comment: The code you included doesn't even reference anything called `fetchIssues`. In other words, it's impossible for us to troubleshoot the cause of the exception.

Comment: syntax error at var issues[]; should be var issues = [];

Comment: I will edit and put the html file.

Comment: EsnEzz is correct, your whole script fails to parse because of that invalid syntax. Fix it and it should  work.